# What would you call an agreement between colleagues of the same work team about establishing common goals regarding an aspect of their job?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I'm trying to determine whether to use the word "cooperative" or "collaborative",  but I'm not sure which would be more appropriate.

I just want to name a document for a meeting in which teachers who teach the same students of a grade level agree on classroom rules and procedures that they will enforce in all classrooms so as to make it as even as possible so student know how they are expected to behave in all classrooms and not have some classrooms be stricter or more lax than others (I'm looking for consistency on the matter).

Answer (score 3):

Don't overthink it.

If it is "an agreement" then call the document "Agreement".  You might title it "Agreement on common standards for classroom behaviour" or something like that.

The teachers are cooperating (they are working towards the same goal) and they might be collaborating (working together on the same project) but you don't need to use either word.